# Which DMV to get database id for sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dmv

Which DMV do I have to join with sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks to get the database ID?

Comment: The documentation has an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-waiting-tasks-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-view-waiting-tasks-for-all-user-processes-with-additional-information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 100 w.session_id, e.database_id, D.name
  FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks w
  LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions e ON w.session_id = e.session_id
  LEFT JOIN sys.databases d ON e.database_id = d.database_id
```